# How to install Visual C coding tools to Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have an older Visual Studio solution with source code of Quake III Arena (a first person shooter game from 1999). It has also source codes of number of useful tools, which need to be edited in order to work with a new game made from Quake 3 engine. All of this code was written in C and in order to work with this older solution (may switch Visual Studio to compatibility mode), I need to first install Visual C tools into my Visual Studio 2015 Community edition copy.

But Google doesn't help much. It still wants me to download Visual C++, but that's something I already have. Visual C is missing and without it the older solution won't work. Is it possible? I want to test making own modification of the game, creating whole new game out of the engine and modifying the tools needed to create assets for the new game, add them new game as an option. Should I download older Visual Studio instead if there is no Visual C for new VS? Where do I download Visual Studio 2008, the one in which the source code was packed?

Comment: Have you tried renaming `src.cpp`into `src.c` with Visual C++ when creating a project ?

Comment: @Badda You misunderstood me. I already have an older Visual Studio project in C. It was created back in 2005 and repaired using VS 2008. But since then Microsoft excluded support for clean C from Visual Studio and I need to restore backward compatibility. I'm not creating new C project...

Comment: Last I checked, the compiler in Visual C++ can compile C code as well. It's just a compiler or project option away.

Comment: @InternetAussie Okay, it may work then. Will try. But in case it won't, where do I download Visual Studio 2008 (an older VS)? Microsoft no longer supports it and it's no longer available to download at their sites.